# magento - custom attributes not showing

Tags: php, magento

i'm trying to implement a layered navigation for my products on magento, so i declared a custom attribute (type 'Dropdown' with scope 'Global' and configured to be used in layered navigation).

i save an attribute set with a 'test' attribute group, and the custom attribute inside.

Then, when i create a customizable product with the saved attribute set, magento display the attribute list with checkboxes, to choose the custom attributes to activate, but in the product creation screen, the 'test' tab isn't showing, neither the custom attribute.

If a put a classic attribute in the 'test' tab, the tab is displaying, but without the custom attribute.

I'm running magento 1.7.0.2 community edition.

Comment: What are the values for 'Show in Frontend' and 'Use for layered navigation' in your attribute config?

Comment: 'yes' and 'filtered (with results)'

Comment: Have you reindexed your "Catalog Search" index? Try re-running all indexes and clearing cache.

Comment: all cache are desactived and the indexes are up to date, and the custom attribute still won't show :(

Comment: found this thread relating to my problem on magento forums : http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/291352/